# Javascript - Goto URL based on Drop Down Selections (continued!)

Tags: javascript, forms, select

This is continued from here: [Javascript / jQuery - Goto URL based on Drop Down Selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230301/javascript-jquery-goto-url-based-on-drop-down-selections)

Some great folks have given me some code examples, but I am having real trouble on where to insert the code in my example form.

Can someone let me know where exactly the code provided in the previous question location should be added in a form to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your JavaScript file you need to bind a function to the `onsubmit` event of your form, so it can do whatever you want.

If you are using jQuery do this:

```
$(function(){

  $('form').submit(function(e){

      window.location.href = $('#dd1').val() +
                             $('#dd2').val()+
                             $('#dd3').val();

      e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Check how it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/WDtGK/2/

added HTML for context

```
 <form>
      <select class="dropdown" id="dd1">
        <option>http://</option>
        <option>ftp://</option>
        <option>https://</option>
      </select>
      <select class="dropdown" id="dd2">
        <option>google</option>
        <option>yahoo</option>
        <option>bbc</option>
        <option>hotmail</option>
      </select>
      <select class="dropdown" id="dd3">
        <option>.com</option>
        <option>.net</option>
        <option>.co.uk</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Go!">
  </form>
```

Comment: Is there any way to add an additional function that checks the URL before going to it, and say, for example, if the last character is an "a" then replace it with a "b" - My URLs sometimes include the "+" character which I need to remove if its the last character in a URL.

So it basically needs to be "if last character is +, remove it"

Comment: You can store the url into a variable and then use regular expressions. A very simple case would be `url = url.replace(/\+$/,'')` which would remove that last `+` in the string.

Comment: I wouldn't use the "+" at all.. rather use: [$('#dd1').val(),$('#dd2').val(),$('#dd3').val()].join("")

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form>
  <select class="dropdown" id="dd1" style="margin-right:10px;width:130px">
    <option>http://</option>
    <option>ftp://</option>
    <option>https://</option>
  </select>
  <select class="dropdown" id="dd2" style="margin-right:10px;width:130px">
    <option>google</option>
    <option>yahoo</option>
    <option>bbc</option>
    <option>hotmail</option>
  </select>
  <select class="dropdown" id="dd3" style="width:130px;margin-right:20px">
    <option>.com</option>
    <option>.net</option>
    <option>.co.uk</option>
  </select>
  <button id="button" type="button">GO</button> <!-- notice this change -->
  </form>
```

In Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#button").click(function(){navigate();});
});

function navigate(){
window.location.href = $('#dd1').val() + $('#dd2').val() + $('#dd3').val();
}
```