# Javascript - If Last Character of a URL string is "+" then remove it...How?

Tags: javascript, string

This is a continuation from an existing question.  [Javascript - Goto URL based on Drop Down Selections (continued!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244987/javascript-goto-url-based-on-drop-down-selections-continued)

I am using dropdown selects to allow my users to build a URL and then hit "Go" to goto it.

Is there any way to add an additional function that checks the URL before going to it?

My URLs sometimes include the "+" character which I need to remove if its the last character in a URL. 
So it basically needs to be "if last character is +, remove it"

This is my code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        window.location.href = 
            $('#dd0').val() +
            $('#dd1').val()+
            $('#dd2').val()+
            $('#dd3').val();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript/679134#679134 almost exact duplicate

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
function removeLastPlus (myUrl)
{
    if (myUrl.substring(myUrl.length-1) == "+")
    {
        myUrl = myUrl.substring(0, myUrl.length-1);
    }

    return myUrl;
}

$(window).load(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        var newUrl = $('#dd0').val() +
            $('#dd1').val()+
            $('#dd2').val()+
            $('#dd3').val();
        newUrl = removeLastPlus(newUrl);
        window.location.href = newUrl;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: What if the URL ends with more than one plus symbol, say three in a row?

Comment: @maerics the OP does not seem to be asking about this case.

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate, from reading OP's code it occurred to me that "dd[0-3]" could contain only plus symbols, but I suppose I'm just being difficult =)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to merge this code with my code.  Is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to check each of these or just all of them together? `$('#dd0').val() +
            $('#dd1').val()+
            $('#dd2').val()+
            $('#dd3').val()`

Comment: It needs to check the combined result of all 3 together, if that makes sense.

Comment: It dosen't seem to be working.  I will see if I can find the issue.

Comment: Still no joy.  When I hit submit after making selections in my dropdowns, it returns the value of my submit button as the URL.   The original code and your code are not talking to one another properly it seems!

Would it help if I setup a jsFiddle?

Comment: This is an example setup on jsFiddle: 
Original Code: http://jsfiddle.net/AsWBL/  With Modified Code: http://jsfiddle.net/AsWBL/1/

Comment: I had ANOTHER typo. I fixed it and now I'm going to try it out on jsFiddle

Comment: Alright, I fixed my typo and it turns out $('#dd0') didn't exist, so I removed that and it's working now: http://jsfiddle.net/AsWBL/4/

Comment: Why use `substr()` and not `charAt()` to retrieve the last character of a string?

Comment: He is trying to get everything BUT the last character of the string if it is a "+" character.

Answer (score 42):

```
var url = /* whatever */;

url = url.replace(/\+$/, '');
```

For example,

```
> 'foobar+'.replace(/\+$/, '');
  "foobar"
```

Answer (score 8):

Found another solution using `str.endsWith("str")`

```js
var str = "Hello this is test+";
if(str.endsWith("+")) {
  str = str.slice(0,-1);
  console.log(str)
}
else {
  console.log(str);
}
```

Also Matt Ball's Replace method looks good. I've updated it to handle the case when there are multiple + at the end.

```js
let str = "hello+++++++++";
str = str.replace(/\++$/, '');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function truncate_plus(input_string) {
    if(input_string.substr(input_string.length - 1, 1) == '+') {
      return input_string.substr(0, input_string.length - 1);
    }
    else
    {
      return input_string;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why use `substr()` and not `charAt()` to retrieve the last character of a string?

Answer (score -1):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        var newUrl = $('#dd0').val() +
            $('#dd1').val()+
            $('#dd2').val()+
            $('#dd3').val();
        newUrl = newUrl.replace(/\+$/, '');
        window.location.href = newUrl;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Just seems easier.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function removeLastPlus(str) {
  if (str.slice(-1) == '+') {
    return str.slice(0, -1);  
  }
  return str;
}
```